# How to add menu send email in magento admin panel?

Tags: magento

I want to add one more menu in magento admin panel.

I want to send mail to customer functionality. I am trying many ways but not working.

How can I add extra one menu in admin panel?

Comment: Here is workable solution http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited . Maybe you will be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You can add code in config.xml file

```
<config>
..... 
<adminhtml>
<menu>
    <custommenu translate="title" module="yourmodule">
        <title>Custom menu</title>
        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
        <children>
            <sendemail>
                <title>Send email</title>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/yourcontroller/index</action> 
            </sendemail>
        </children>
    </custommenu>
</menu>
 <acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>                
                <custommenu translate="title" module="yourmodule">
                    <title>Custom menu</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                </custommenu>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl> 
</adminhtml>  
.....
</config>
```